# IE <= 8 .splice() not working

Tags: javascript

I have some simple code you can see in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kXxX/). It alerts properly in all browsers and IE9, but not IE8 or 7.

```
var func = function( x ) {
    var slice = [].slice,
        args = slice.call( arguments ),
        pass = args.splice(1);

    alert( pass );

};

func( 'a', 1, 2 );
```

**EDIT**
Using the solution I posted what I used here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7kXxX/4/

I am using this in a case where I don't know how many arguments are coming, which is why I'm using "arguments"

Comment: what do you expect to be alerted?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [ECMAScript 3rd edition standard](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4.4.12) requires the second `deleteCount` argument:

```
Array.prototype.splice(start, deleteCount [, item1 [, item2[,...]]])
```

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wctc5k7s%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) show that IE follows this standard:

```
arrayObj.splice(start, deleteCount, [item1[, item2[, . . . [,itemN]]]])
```

Firefox's SpiderMonkey allows the [second argument to be optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (as do other modern browsers):

```
array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])
array.splice(index[, howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]]])
```

Description:

> **howMany** 
>   An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If howMany is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you
>   should specify at least one new element. If no howMany parameter is
>   specified (second syntax above, which is a SpiderMonkey extension),
>   all elements after index are removed.

Sources:

- http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4.4.12
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wctc5k7s%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 5):

Splice has a required second argument:

http://jsfiddle.net/7kXxX/2/

```
pass = args.splice(1,2);
```

The optional second argument is an extension in newer browsers that assume the rest of the array if left undefined

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Slice would be more appropriate if you want elements from 1 - to the end, doesn't look like there is any reason to remove elements from args.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to the Array.prototype.splice in IE ([read more here](http://cmacrander.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/array-prototype-splice/)):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var originalSplice = Array.prototype.splice;
    Array.prototype.splice = function (start, deleteCount) {
        // convert the weird, not-really-an-array arguments array to a real one
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // IE requires deleteCount; set default value if it doesn't exist
        if (deleteCount === undefined) {
            args[1] = this.length - start;
        }
        // call the original function with the patched arguments
        return originalSplice.apply(this, args);
    };
}());
```

Comment: No need to make `args` an array. Just use the `arguments` object.

Comment: This is needed for IE 6-9. According to my browserstack research, IE 6-9 silently fails to write to the arguments object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var func = function (x) 
{
    alert ([].slice.call (arguments, 1))
}

func( 'a', 1, 2 );
```

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more and explain what you did. Just the code does not cut it!

Comment: On the other hand, slice is far more appropriate for the presented use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this particular issue, but have you tried [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com)? It has some methods that might work for you (I believe replacing splice with from would work).