# Bootstrap (2) multiple datepickers in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have three date fields spread across three forms on a single page.
Each date field uses bootstrap datepicker.
Each field is a date-of-birth and as such, all three are updated whenever any one is changed.

This all works perfectly in FF, Chrome etc.

However, when you get to IE8/7 the datepicker, instead of clearing the input field, concatenates the new value in a comma separated list style.
I've tried using multidate: false (even though that's the default) but it has no effect.

Any ideas ?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/xaH2n/

Here's the code:

```
// Set default value
$("#oneDate").val("01/01/1990");
$("#twoDate").val("01/01/1990");
$("#threeDate").val("01/01/1990");

var defaultDate = "25/12/1990";

// Set up datepicker
$("#oneDate, #twoDate, #threeDate").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "-89y",
    endDate: "-17y",
    startView: 2,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "top left"
}).on("changeDate", function() {
    var newDoB = $(this).val();

    $("#oneDate").datepicker("update", newDoB);
    $("#twoDate").datepicker("update", newDoB);
    $("#threeDate").datepicker("update", newDoB);
});

// Reset value
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#oneDate").datepicker("update", defaultDate);
    $("#twoDate").datepicker("update", defaultDate);
    $("#threeDate").datepicker("update", defaultDate);
});
```

Hint:
*We've found, to get a fiddle running in IE, log into your account in chrome/FF and open the fiddle. Then go to http://jsfiddle.net/draft in IE and log in and you fiddle should appear.*

Comment: what if you change `$('#id').datepicker("update", newDoB);` with `$('#id').val(newDoB)`?

Comment: Hi @Aguardientico : We tried that, it still works in FF & Chrome but no change in IE :o(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually with internet explorer.

The splice function in internet explorer actually requires an extra parameter to function the way that Firefox and Chrome do.
[IE <= 8 .splice() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332969/ie-8-splice-not-working)

If you look at the bootstrap-datepicker.js code it contains

```
this.splice(0);
```

So your solutions are to either grab the master branch of bootstrap-datepicker with an updated fix (which has not been released :/)
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

OR

'fix' how the splice(0) function works in internet explorer via javascript
http://www.to-string.com/2012/05/29/fixing-splice-in-older-versions-of-internet-explorer-8-and-olders/