# Delete an element from an array using its value in javaScript which supports IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to delete one item from the array using its value instead of index which will work on IE8. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my array:

```
var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

The result should be something like:

delete operation:

```
myArray.splice('three');
```

result:

```
myArray =['one', 'two'];
```

I tried this but its not working in IE8.

```
angular.forEach($scope.leftList, function (leftItems) {
    var arrlen = $scope.rightList.length;
    for (var j = 0; j<arrlen; j++) {
        if (leftItems == $scope.rightList[j]) {
            $scope.rightList = $scope.rightList.slice(0, j).concat($scope.rightList.slice(j+1, arrlen));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What if `'three'` occurs more than once?

Comment: What kind of values do you have in array, words only? One word per item?

Comment: "*I want to...*" - but you've shown no code to suggest you've started on that; how far did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes words only but it can contain more than one word per item.

Comment: @David. I added my code in question. Its not working in IE8

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 is [*unsupported* and *untested*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) as of Angular 1.3. Will you *only* be using AngularJS 1.2 for this project moving forward?

Comment: @JonathanSampson. I am using AngularJS 1.2 in my project.

Comment: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/function/angular.forEach does it internally handle IE8 not having Array.prototype.forEach?

Comment: @user3842029 What exactly does "not working" mean? what error does it throw? what does it do instead of working?

Comment: Is this your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8333160/123415

Comment: It was freezing my application when I try to delete. But anyways i got the answer below. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `split` and `join` methods and in the right moment also include some regex replace:

```js
var myArray = ['one item', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'fourth item'];
function clearFromArray(item, array) {
 var re1 = new RegExp(item,"g");
 var re2 = new RegExp('(##)+',"g");
 return array.join('##').replace(re1, '').replace(re2, '##').split('##');
};
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = clearFromArray('two', myArray);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Also on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbr4f0fy/1/).